# Black bars in media-vimeo plugin

Tags: media

Hi is it possible to remove black bars in media-vimeo plugin? There is line in player.css style which controls it, but I can't edit it, because this file is loaded inside of iframe.

[image]

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 0):

No this is a video scaling and proportion issue for the player (or your embed code size). If Vimeo allows you to not show these black bars (you'd have to goto the Vimeo site and compare many many videos) ... you would need to figure out the correct aspect ratio to record you're video at so that these bars are not needed in the embed width of the player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the css on the page that is inside the iframe. If you change the dimensions of the box that surrounds the player you should be able to get the black bars to dissapear. Have a play with firebug.

Comment: What? A client site cannot edit what is inside of or affect an iframe.

Comment: Well, you can using Firebug in Firefox (but not firebug lite). It just won't be possible to save the changes unless you are able to edit the css attached to the child page. Even so just changing the dimensions of the iframe may have the desired affect.

Comment: but even if I can edit it, it really doesn't help, because I can't save it.

Comment: So can save the dimensions of the iframe...